# Spring Boot not calling SuccessfulAuthentication handler

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

I have a project composed of a Spring Boot backend that offers up RESTful services to an Angular 5 front end.

I'm currently trying to implement proper authentication between the front and back ends. To that end I've added a standard Spring authentications scheme consisting of an AuthenticationFilter, AuthorizationFilter, WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor and an AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

In the WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor I've configured things as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ComixEdWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private ComixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/comics/count", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/comics/**", "/pages/**").hasRole("READER")
                .antMatchers("/files/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and()
            .addFilter(new ComixEdAuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
            .addFilter(new ComixEdAuthorizationFilter(this.authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // @formatter:on
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
}
```

All pieces get called as expected, except for the ComixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler, which is never called. I've stepped through the AuthenticatorFilter and see things working as expected, and the front end is getting a 200 response. But I need the AuthenticationSuccessHandler to be invoked as well to put some tokens into the response.

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/mcpierce/comixed/tree/feature/issue-110).

Answer (score 1):

I've happened upon the same problem as yours, and while it's too late for you, my solution might help somebody else (just note that I don't really know what I'm doing):

I don't know how exactly your `ComixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler` looked like since the GitHub link is dead now, but mine extends  `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and overrides the method:

```
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication);
```

...which apparently was what caused problems. What does work is this:

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication);
```

So it appears that the method taking `chain` as an argument simply isn't the correct method to override in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How are u creating the authenticationSuccessHandler class?

A example of a handler that i use is this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(flashLoginSuccessHandler())
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .deleteCookies("SESSION")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(flashLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
            .userDetailsService(flashUserDetailsService)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler flashLoginSuccessHandler() {
    return new FlashLoginSuccessHandler();
}
```

And FlashLoginSuccessHandler have to extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
public class FlashLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

You can overwrite the response object to add your custom data as u want.

Comment: The AuthenticationSuccessHandler is created (via @Component) and autowired (via @Autowired) by Spring.

Comment: But you can implement your own.

Comment: I did write my own, called ComixedAuthenticationSuccessHandler. Please look at the code I quoted in the original question.

Comment: Try using a bean method like i commented before.
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler comixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new ComixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

And use it:

http.formLogin().successHandler(comixEdAuthenticationSuccessHandler())


And *extends* SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler instead of implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: maybe when you overwrite authenticationsuccesshandler you are missing things that spring should do by default

Comment: I've verified that, in the code where it's setting the success handler, it actually has the bean I'm providing. I've tried extending the Simple* class rather than implementing the interface, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might be getting missed? I've been at this off and on and can't find a solution.